Is there a way to plot to a table without R characters (that is, "i", "o" or "u") in gnuplot?
Is there a way to plot to a table without R characters (that is, "i", "o" or "u") in gnuplot for windows?
I was trying to sort a file whose name is FILE:
set format y ""
set table $Data
plot FILE  u 1:2:1 smooth zsort
unset table

expecting to get rid of the "i" after each line thanks to the set format y ""; but when printing $Data I got them all again. For multicolumn files, you get a column of those characters after each column of numbers.

What is the exact reason that you want to avoid these letters in an additional column? These letters don't harm for plotting. Is there maybe more behind which we don't know?

Just to avoid unnecessary letters (mainly for many-column files). Not big deal though. Besides, I was trying to use your script link that deals with the file "FILE" that doesn't have those characters. Initially I changed the columns u 1:2:3 by u 1:3:5 and worked well but I got an error message... Now without those characters it's all right except for straight lines that appear enclosing the various colored parts (that you don't have in your output). I'll work on that though

ok, I see. Apparently, this problem is solved since you accepted the answer. If you have an issue with something else, please open a new question including a minimal example, ideally including data, script and output.

For plotting to a datablock/table and avoiding an extra column of i, o or u, you have the plotting style with table (check help with table). However, smooth and with table will not work together. So, you need a two step process.
Data: SO78337085.dat
4   4.1
3   3.1
7   7.1
1   1.1
9   9.1
6   6.1
5   5.1
2   2.1
8   8.1

Script: (requires gnuplot>=5.4.0, because of smooth zsort)
### sort data without extra header and range column
reset session

FILE = "SO78337085.dat"
set table $Data
    plot FILE u 1:2:1 smooth zsort
unset table
print $Data

set table $Data2
    plot $Data u 1:2 w table
unset table
print $Data2
### end of script

Result:
# Curve 0 of 1, 9 points
# Curve title: "FILE u 1:2:1"
# x y type
 1  1.1  i
 2  2.1  i
 3  3.1  i
 4  4.1  i
 5  5.1  i
 6  6.1  i
 7  7.1  i
 8  8.1  i
 9  9.1  i


 1       1.1
 2       2.1
 3       3.1
 4       4.1
 5       5.1
 6       6.1
 7       7.1
 8       8.1
 9       9.1

